# what is __PRIVATE_NEXTJS_INTERNALS_TREE for?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, browser-history

While using History API on Next.js project, I found a data called '__PRIVATE_NEXTJS_INTERNALS_TREE' in `state` field of history object.

To find out what exactly this field for, I tried to search from official docs of Next.js, google on Stack Overflow, search on Next.js GitHub issue tabs, but found nothing related.

What is this data exactly for?

[image]

to reproduce, follow below code

```
// any next.js project

console.log(window.history.state)
```

1. Reading Offical Documents
2. Search for articles from stack overflow
3. look up on Next.js github issue tabs

Expecting what __PRIVATE_NEXTJS_INTERNALS_TREE is for.

Comment: Like the name suggests, it's a private internal variable used by Next.js. It's not mean to be used by you as an end user, so it won't be documented. Variables starting with underscores in Javascript by convention mean "private", as in "don't mess with me, this isn't your data." You can read [the source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/23955574ae18a81a572d620f299528244e3a1bd1/packages/next/src/client/components/app-router.tsx#L224) if you want to see how Next.js internally uses this variable.